# Too many faces after retopology

Tags: faces, retopology

[image]I finally finished my retopology, but really confused about applying modifiers to make it smooth. After applying Multires and Shrinkwrap i have so many faces and triangles and it leaving me really confused because isnt retopology suppoused to make it low poly. After that i tried to use decimate modifier to reduce the amount of faces but it didnt work and the whole model looks very low quality. (Also i could use decimate only on head because my computer would just crash if i wanted to do whole body). Maybe im doing something wrong? I tried to find what modifiers to use to finish retopology and stuff but couldnt find any answers.

[image]

my retopo before applying modifiers
[image]

and after apllying multires

Comment: Hello, it's a bit confusing, please show how the topology looks like, also tell what you want to do with your character, if you want to rig and animate you need a good topology and you'll most probably need to do it manually because no modifier can do it properly. You can try Quad Remesher though but it's not free and anyway you'll probably need to make some manual corrections

Comment: hello so i did my retopology manually i edited my question and added pictures so you can see what happens after i apply it

Comment: the topology seems rather good, could you please describe the problem you're talking about?

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what exactly the question is supposed to be. Obviously, if you add more geometry with modifiers you will have more geometry. Retopology is to reduce the amount of geometry and make it suitable for deformations when animating. You should choose the level of detail for that when doing retopology and accept the fact that you will have more geometry if you subdivide it. Decimating it afterwards makes little sense since it will produce topology not suitable for deformations.

Comment: It may also make sense to have a low poly model subdivided with a modifier because, you can then reduce complexity at any time if you need better performance during animation process, but a smooth model for rendering final result.

Comment: so basically when im applying multires mod i have too many triamgles (edited the question and added another pic) but in the tutorial i watched the model is low poly and looks smooth and doesn't have that many triangles and faces after applying modifiers 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XDfs63C5qYA&list=PLe0O-ypJqvKw6meu68TlU0_motrjcnrva&index=5 heres the tutorial i follow

Comment: Well, yes. What's your question about this? If you want less geometry, don't apply multires or subdivision modifiers. That's pretty much how it works. Maybe you make too many subdivision levels - one or two should be enough in most cases. You could have more if you don't plan to apply it, but make a high resolution version and then bake the detail into textures for the lower detail model.

Comment: is baking helps with keeping it smooth? im planing to just rig it and put in to the pose like a model. Is not applying multires would affect it if not i think i can jyst leave it unapplied

Comment: Not really. Smooth shading or a baked normals may make the model look smoother to some degree, but subdividing helps with smoothing in case of low poly model. You can also smooth vertices if you have dense uneven mesh, but this doesn't seem to apply here. Subdividing has a cost of more geometry as you can see. Baking is used primarily for "faking" finer detail on lower resolution mesh. If you want the model to be smooth, you have to have more geometry. You are supposed to look for balance here to have it just as smooth as it's enough, but not too much so it's still easy enough to work with.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Just to clarify it is not necessary to apply multires modifier?

Comment: @banana Why do you have a _Multires_ modifier at all? If you want to compare your model to the one in the tutorial you showed, there is only a _Mirror_ modifier so he only has to model one side, and a _Subdivision Surface_ modifier set only to _Level_ 2.

Comment: And do not "apply" the subdivision modifier.

Comment: thank you so much it working now!